# На  природе.

Tags: нормы-языка

*Мы отмечали день рожденья на природе.*   *Мы едем на природу.*

Вот эти "на природе", "на природу" в общем-то правильно понимаются носителями языка. Но являются ли эти выражения нормативными?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Одно из значений слова природа - **места вне городов** (поля, леса, горы, водные пространства). Любоваться природой. На лоне природы. Выезжать на природу. Последнее словосочетание у Ожегова дается как просторечное (просторечие находится за рамками литературного языка), а вот в толковом словаре  Кузнецова (на "Грамоте") рядом с "поехать на природу" даже пометы *разговорное* нет. ВОт такие крайности. Я бы выбрала золотую середину - разговорное. В книжной речи вместо "поехали на природу" выбрала бы вариант "поехали за город", "в лес", "на речку" и т.п.